# ZK - org.zkoss.util.IllegalSyntaxException: only allow one string of @command

Tags: java, zk

I have the following zul

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<zk>
    <window apply="org.zkoss.bind.BindComposer" viewModel="@id('vm') @init('MyViewModel')"> 
        <button onClick="@command('myCommand', value='myValue')" />
    </window>
</zk>
```

with a button inside which calls a `command` inside the view model passing a parameter called value

The page returns the following error:

```
org.zkoss.util.IllegalSyntaxException: only allow one string of @command,but contains ['myCommand', 'myValue'
```

ZK version: 7.0.4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please have a look below code,please remove `''` from argument it will work

```
<button label="MyButton" onClick="@command('myCommand', somevalue=myValue)"/>
```

Here are some example from documents

```
<button label="Save" onClick="@command('saveOrder')" />

<button label="Delete" onClick="@command(empty vm.selected.id?'deleteOrder':'confirmDelete')" />

<button label="Index" onClick="@command('showIndex', index=10, keyword='myKeyword')"/>
```

More Information you can find

> Notice that value is a reserved word, you should avoid to use it as an
>   arbitraryKey.

[books.zkoss.org/zk-mvvm-book/8.0/syntax/databindingcommand.html](http://%20%09%20books.zkoss.org/zk-mvvm-book/8.0/syntax/databindingcommand.html)

Comment: nope: `org.zkoss.util.IllegalSyntaxException: only allow one string of @command,but contains ['myCommand', myValue]`

Comment: Which version you r using

Comment: you rock! the last article was the one I was desperately searching yesterday

Comment: the problem was already solved after my late answer. I created the question to help others in the future

Comment: Thanks @AlexGreg will not add answer in your future questions. You better know then me.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is the name of the parameter passed to the command. `value` is a reserved word for the `@command` expression.

So the solution here is to rename the parameter name from `value` to anything else

EDIT:

@Subodh Joshi found the [article](http://books.zkoss.org/zk-mvvm-book/8.0/syntax/databindingcommand.html) where points that `value` is a reserved word